# How do I use md5 authentication in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, authentication, md5

I am creating a role in postgresql. The documentation gives me the following example with clear-text password:

```sql
CREATE ROLE foo WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'secret'
```

My task is to use MD5 instead of a clear-text password because it is not secure enough. However, the documentation merely mentioned the possibility to use md5 instead of a password, without giving any example code. I wonder how could I re-write the code above to implement MD5? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Note that the password is stored in md5 (or SCRAM) even if you specified it in plain text.

Answer (score 2):

To change the authentication method:

1. ```
   Open a terminal window
   ```
2. ```
   Change into the postgres bin directory
   ```

Example:  cd /usr/local/pgsql/bin

Note:  Depending on your install environment the path to the bin directory may vary.

3. ```
   Type su – postgres and press Enter.  This will change the logged in to the postgres user.
   ```
4. ```
   From the bin directory type ./psql
   ```
5. ```
   Type ALTER USER postgres password 'your shell account postgres password'; and press Enter.  ALTER ROLE should be displayed.
   ```
6. ```
   Type \q and press Enter
   ```
7. ```
   Type vi /path to data directory/pg_hba.conf and press Enter
   ```
8. ```
   Modify the line at the bottom of the config file to resemble one of these examples.
   ```

Note:  You will probably only have to change the word trust to md5.  The line or lines should already exist.

host     all        postgres           your.ip your.subnet      md5

host     all        all                    your.ip  your.subnet     md5

Note:  If you are using vi as the editor press i to insert text

9. ```
   Save the changes
   ```

Note:   If you are using vi as the editor press i to insert then press :wq! to save the changes.

10. From the postgres bin directory type./pg_ctl restart -D /usr/local/pgsql/data and press Enter

Comment: Thank you for your help! Is it possible to conduct it within pgAdmin?

Comment: yes it is possible

Comment: How to do that on pgadmin?